# Firebase Admin Module not found: 'dns'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-admin

I just installed the Firebase Admin SDK with "npm install firebase-admin --save" and see the error on "npm start". Is there any dependency- that I missed?

> **Failed to compile.**
>
> Error in ./~/firebase-admin/~/isemail/lib/isemail.js Module not found:
>   'dns' in
>   C:\webroot\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\isemail\lib
>
> @ ./~/firebase-admin/~/isemail/lib/isemail.js 45:10-24

Comment: I do not know what Firebase Admin SDK is, but when you miss 'dns' module, you can install it by 'npm i dns'

Comment: You may be right, I am just wondering, is 'DNS' a dependency in this firebase admin SDK. I did not see any prerequisite in installation process.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue. `npm i dns` doesn't help

Comment: Yes, I found something alternative. Firebase Admin does not work on browser base, firebase provided an alternative called "Functions". Firebase Admin modules can call inside the functions. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Answer (score 1):

It does not work in the browser, but if for some reason you have to access all the data at once, take a look at this: https://github.com/taptalk/fireman